# Package equivalent visibility modifier in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm writing a program in which I'm using the factory pattern. I have an interface called **AssetFundCalculator** and a class named **AssetFundCalculatorImpl** which implements the interface.

The **AssetFundValidator** class validates some inputs, and is able to instantiate a valid **AssetFundCalculatorImpl**.

I'd like if the rest of the program would only know about the interface, and not about the **AssetFundCalculatorImpl**, so that only the **AssetFundValidator** could instantiate it.

My package structure is looking like this:

[image]

In Java, I would give package visibility modifier to the **AssetFundCalculatorImpl** class, or it's constructor, and it would solve the issue, but in Kotlin, there is no package visibility modifier.

Is there a solution to this? 
I don't want to put this code to a separately compiled module, so the **internal** modifier is not going to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put `AssetFundValidator` and `AssetFundCalculatorImpl` into the same file and mark `AssetFundCalculatorImpl` as `private`. In that case it will only be accessible to code in the same file, including `AssertFundValidator`, but not to any code in other parts of the program.

Comment: After all I didn't use this solution, I really don't like putting two classes in one file. What was the reason for leaving out the package modifier from the language?

Comment: You should get used to putting multiple classes in one file, it's a very common pattern in Kotlin. We didn't include package-local visibility because it's not a good way to hide anything: a user of a module can create classes in the same package that the module uses and thus get access to package-local parts of that module.

Comment: But this way I have to put an 80 and a 130 lines long class in the same file, and the code becomes long enough to make it harder to read and navigate. I think it's not very clean. It also makes unit testing harder, since I have to use the factory in the unit test, to get an instance, so it's not so much of a 'unit' test anymore.

Comment: @yole Even if package visibility is "not a good way to hide anything", it doesn't invalidate it as a good pattern, i.e if you want to create a StorageAPI which has public access and you define within the same package/sub-packages different ways of persistence/caching (file, db, ram, etc.) that you don't want accessible from out of the "storage" package but to be handled by the StorageAPI, is an example that justifies package visibility, not even considering adding thousands of lines of code to a class which englobes a wider concept just to fit Kotlin's taste.

Comment: There is a wider concern/issue/question, call it whatever fits best here. JVM is an interpreter for Java language and Java language is the programming interface for the JVM, in that respect Java is equivalent to JVM. How does, "internal" map to Java/JVM? How does one create the equivalent of "package" access in Kotlin. Saying that Kotlin and Java are interoperable is widely flawed, I'd say, unless 1 to 1 mapping can be done between the two.
So, if one has Factory initialiser in Java that deals with many classes for various cases, then all these classes shall end up in 1 absurdly gigantic file